# Python installation mess on Mac OS X, cannot run python

Tags: python, macos, bash, shell, installation

I stupidly downloaded python 3.2.2 and since then writing 'python' in the terminal yields 'command not found'. Also, when starting the terminal I get this:

Last login: Wed May 2 23:17:28 on ttys001
-bash: export: `folder]:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Applications/android-sdk-mac_86/tools:/Applications/android-sdk-mac_86/platform-tools:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/ant/bin': not a valid identifier

Why the Android SDK folder is there is beyond me. It's all jazzed up. Any ideas how can I remove the offending file, folder or fix his problem? I've checked the System Profiler and python 2.6.1 and 2.7.2.5 shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the binary was not overridden it's typically located in

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/X.X/bin/python
```

where `X.X` is your version (probably 2.7) if it's not located there it *could* be sometimes found in

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/X.X/bin/python
```

If you find the right binary and can run it, go ahead and start symlinking it where you need to and making the necessary patches. My first piece of advice would be changing your `Current` to point to the old version.

```
 sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/X.X /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current
```

or

```
sudo ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/X.X /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current
```

Comment: Both /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/ and /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/ contains python folders, 2.5 is in both folder.

Comment: I don't know how you don't have sudo but it sounds like your bash profile is indeed incorrect somehow. You could try creating a new user copy the profile or if you have another existing user profile you could use that as a baseline for correcting yours.

Answer (score 1):

Something got messed up in your `$PATH`.  Have a look in `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, etc., and look for a line starting with `export` that doesn't end cleanly.

Comment: Entering open ./profile yields 'open - command not found' What the heck?

Comment: Try using vim... `vim ~/.profile` and pray you have at least that if not use full paths for everything `/usr/bin/vim ~/.profile`

Comment: Your `$PATH` is messed up, expect many commands not to work without specifying the full path to them, i.e., `/usr/bin/open`.  I'd actually recommend using TextEdit.app and cmd-shift-. to show files starting with '.'

Comment: vim: command not found Now I have to find a way to repair the bash profile, I assume.

Answer (score 1):

A very ugly solution to your profile problem since `$PATH` seems to be very wrong (as was mentioned by blahdiblah)

```
/bin/cp ~/.profile /tmp/bkup_profile
/bin/cat /tmp/bkup_profile | /usr/bin/grep -v "PATH" > ~/.profile
```

Open a new terminal and see if you can run commands normally try `ls`, `echo`, `sudo` for example.

Comment: ls and sudo are 'command not found', echo creates a new, empty line

Comment: It worked:/bin/cp ~/.profile /tmp/bkup_profile
/bin/cat /tmp/bkup_profile | /usr/bin/grep -v "PATH" > ~/.profile

Comment: Now ls yields a list for instance, sudo as well! Thanks very much!

Comment: If you're all settled and everything is working again for you click the Check Mark under the answer as well as the up-arrow for the answer if you're satisfied and it helped you, this way if someone else has a problem they can reference my answer for help as well.